# Is there a special way to solve a linear system with many zero outputs?

Tags: linear-algebra

In a linear system, I have many (several hundred) zero outputs and too few non-zero outputs, i.e.,
$\begin{bmatrix}A& B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}y_1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are large dense matrices.

Is there a smart way to make use of this feature while 
computing the input  $\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ using linear solvers.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Are $A,B,C,D$ block matrices or numbers?

Comment: Look up algorithms for sparse matricies.

Comment: @MJay1985 Sparse matrix methods typically handle when the matrix with $A,B,C,D$ is sparse. Here we have the case where the vector $x$ is perpendicular to many of the rows of a potentially dense matrix.

Comment: Ah now i get it. so the right hand side has lots of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to invert your matrix, you'd only have to invert the first few columns, as when you multiply the inverted matrix by your $y$ vector, the 0s at the end of the $y$ vector will zero out all the corresponding columns of the inverted matrix.

The practical question is whether you can write a "half - inversion" algorithm that's faster than a standard algorithm can invert the whole thing!